# WebSocket client can not connect to Java spring WebSocket server using different port

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I am using Java Spring WebSocket to create a WebSocket server, it actually works if WebSocket client is created from the SAME server.

This is my server side code, very simple

```
// WebSocketConfig.java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer  {
    @Autowired
    SocketTextHandler socketTextHandler;

    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(socketTextHandler, "/sockets");
    }
    
}
```

```
// SocketTextHandler.java
@Component
public class SocketTextHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)
            throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        String payload = message.getPayload();
        System.out.println("16: " + session.getId());
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Resp: " + payload));
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception) {
        System.out.println("Server transport error: " + exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Then I put the following WebSocket client in the Spring boot static index.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    Hello
    <script>
      console.log('start');
      const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/sockets');
      ws.onopen = function(evt) {
        console.log('onopen', evt);
      }
      ws.onerror = function(evt) {
        console.log('onerror', evt);
      }
      console.log('done');
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then I visit `http://localhost:8080/index.html`, there is no error and I can see the `console.log('onopen', evt)` log.

However, my WebSocket client should be running on a different port `http://localhost:3000`, I use the same index.html, but when I visit `http://localhost:3000/index.html`, there is always this error `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/sockets' failed` in console

I am wondering are WebSockets required to be connected from the same server? Or I missed something.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to change the port number in `new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/sockets')`

Comment: @tgdavies, would you be more specific? my WebSocket server is on port 8080, port 3000 is a WebSocket client, which want to connect to 8080

Comment: I see, I thought you'd moved your whole server. Apologies.

Comment: @tgdavies NP! thank you for looking into it

Comment: What do you see in the server logs for a failed connection?

Comment: @tgdavies I found the root cause, it is actually very simple, after registering the websocket in WebSocketConfig.java, should also set origins, e.g `setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:8080");`, or `setAllowedOrigins("*");` to accept any clients.

Answer (score 6):

for anyone who also encounter this, `registry.addHandler(socketTextHandler, "/sockets").setAllowedOrigins("*");` will resolve the issue